# File only saving final value instead of all values

Tags: python

I have the following small script:

```
startingvalue = .01
roughendvalue = 1000000
multiplicationfactor = 2
value = startingvalue
name = "the power of exponential functions"
while value < roughendvalue:

    if value < roughendvalue:
        value = value*multiplicationfactor
    file = open(str(name) + ".txt", "w+")
    file.write(str(value))
    file.close()
    print(value)
        
file.close()
```

Right now it only saves the final output `1342177.28` to a file and prints it; however, I want it to save all the intermediate values to the file as well.
How do I change it to save all of the values and not just the final value?

Comment: You're overwriting the file each time through the loop. Open it once before the loop, not every time.

Comment: P.S. Why do you use `w+` mode instead of `w`? The `+` is only needed if you're also reading the file. For some reason almost all questions seem to use `+` even when not needed.

Comment: Thats true so i should just open it once before the loop?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. You should also use `with`.

Comment: `with open(str(name)+".txt", "w") as file:`

Comment: yup figured it out just completely removed the file open in the loop and put one out side of the loop

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the "w+" by "a", put the file = open(str(name) + ".txt", "w+") before the loop and file.close() after the loop and modify :

```
file.write(str(value)+'\n')
```

it you will have each value on a line, so you can read them with :

```
file = open(str(name) + ".txt", "r")
ex_list=[]
for f in file.readlines() :
  ex_list.append(float(f))
file.close()
```

Comment: yeah im new to python so not sure what the list or float means but makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing the file open within the loop and just put one outside of the loop and that's all I needed to fix.

```
    roughendvalue = 1000000
    multiplicationfactor = 2
    value = 0.01
    name = "the power of exponential functions"
    file = open(str(name) + ".txt", "w+")
    while value < roughendvalue:

        if value < roughendvalue:
             value = value*multiplicationfactor
        file.write(str(value) + "\n")
        print(value)
        

    file.close()
```